# How can I make all of the windows default font/window smaller? Or zoom to .90 for my entire desktop

Tags: 20.04, fonts, display-resolution, configuration

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and want to make all of the fonts across all of my applications smaller (like Windows supports).  For example, in Windows I could make the zoom level 125%, 150%, 200%.

The built in Ubuntu system  Settings | Displays allows you to zoom but not reduce zoom.

[image]

And I see something similar to that in Ubuntu under Settings | Universal Access | Zoom Options

[image]

But those aren't quite what I'm looking for as this solution zooms a portion of the screen (like a magnifying glass) and does not support zoom out.

### Searching for a solution

Stack overflow has several questions but not this one.  Some are:

- https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ubuntu+how+can+I+make+my+default+font%2Fwindow+smaller%3F - General search on SO
- [Make windows smaller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151753/make-windows-smaller) - This worked but only changed the title bar not the font sizes.
- [How can I make fonts in the top panel smaller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203475/how-can-i-make-fonts-in-the-top-panel-smaller) - similar to the above
- [Ubuntu GNOME and high resolution screen: icons in QT apps are too small. How to solve?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771673/ubuntu-gnome-and-high-resolution-screen-icons-in-qt-apps-are-too-small-how-to/826405#826405)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the application "Tweaks" (Gnome Tweaks). That exposes a setting to change the font scaling on the "Fonts" tab.

Alternatively, the setting can be changed using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.8
```

will reduce the overall font sizes.

Reset to default with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

Comment: This worked for several apps (chromium browser, gnome-terminal) which are the main things I'm interested in.  IntelliJ, however, did not resize, nor did terminator.